# egrep: CPU and memory usage

Tags: perl, unix, memory, cpu

My Linux machine has 16 processors and free memory of 70 GB but when I run an `egrep` command, the command is using (checked through the `top` command) 100% of CPU and 0.5 of memory:

```
22391 aime      25   0 22.5g 337m  880 R 100.1  0.5   1094:06 egrep
```

That means that only 1 out of 16 CPUs are used.

How can  I improve the performance here or make my `egrep` use more CPUs?

I am actually `grep`ping in the directory structure which is 40 GB in terms of data size.

The approximate regex is :

```
egrep -H -i -R -a -o -n ([[:alnum:]_\.]+@[[:alnum:]_\.]*(xyz|abc)\.com) <dir>
```

Also , since  I am running this command through Perl script, can ForkManager help me in this regard ?

Thanks

Comment: Split the file into separate segments and run separate egrep commands against each segment?  How big of a file are you processing?  Are you not I/O bound anyway?  What is the regex you're using?

Comment: Please edit your post to include info Jonathan has asked for. good luck.

Comment: "The *approximate* regex"? Are you not *sure*?

Comment: That is because I have modified it here before putting .

Comment: This question is better suited to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use grep efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200591/how-to-use-grep-efficiently)

Answer (score 2):

The CPU utilization issue is rooted in threading. egrep = 1 thread => 1 cpu.
If you want to use more CPUs, then you need to split up the task into 16 smaller tasks.
I suggest dividing the data into 16 chunks and running one egrep on each, and make sure they're assigned to different CPUs each.

Comment: How to make sure that each egrep is assigned to different CPU ? I am firing the egrep command through a PERL script ?

Comment: You should leave that to the Linux kernel (or whatever OS you are using). If you create one process for each CPU, the load will in most cases be split evenly among the CPUs.

Comment: What Krumelur said. However, this being such big operations, you might want to set the afinity manually. How to do this depend on the linux flavour of choice.

Comment: Look into the `-P` flag of `xargs` as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200591/how-to-use-grep-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

- If you're using a Perl script anyway, why not use Perl to do the matching?
- From a shell script, `find` plus [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) (or `xargs -P`, as Schwern writes) are the most obvious way of applying `egrep` on your input files in parallel; they can obviously be invoked from Perl as well, or you can use Perl equivalents (e.g. [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/File/Find.pm)).
- You can parallellize by piping greps: the first to do very quick, simple pre-filtering, the next to do exact, expensive matching - but whether this approach can save you any time depends on what you need to match and on egrep implementation details that I'm not familiar with.